# How to print the output in the same page using flask app and html

Tags: python, html, flask

This is my index.html where I am collecting the details to predict price value and want display it at the end of the page. But I'm getting the output in a fresh page . I used flask app to integrate html with the ML model.

```
<body>
     <div class="container">
     <div class="title">Predict Here</div>
     <div class="content">
      <form action="/predict" method="post">
        <div class="user-details">
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="area_type">Area Type</span>
            <select name="area_type" id=area_type><br><br>
              <option value= "Select">Select<option>
              <option value= "Plot Area">Plot Area<option>
              <option value= "Super built-up Area">Super built-up Area<option>
              <option value= "Built-up Area">Built-up Area<option>
             </select><br>
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Total Sqft</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the Total_sqrft" name="sqft" required>
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Bedrooms</span>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter no. of Bedrooms" min="1" name="bedroom" >
          </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Bathrooms</span>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter no. of Bathrooms"  min="1" name="bathroom" >
           </div>
          <div class="input-box">
            <span class="details">Year</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the Year"  maxlength="4" name="year" required>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <input type="submit" value="Predict">
        </div>
        <p>{{ price }}</p>
```

This is my Flask app code. I want to show the value of price calculated here on the same html but it is appearing on a new page. Here, model.pkl is the pickle file

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pickle
import array as arr
app = Flask(__name__)
pkl_file = open('model.pkl','rb')
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
index_dict = pickle.load(pkl_file)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    #return render_template('index.html')
    return "Go to /predict to find the estimated price of your house"


@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method=='POST':
        result = request.form
        
        area_type = result.get("area_type")
        print(area_type)
        if area_type == 'Super built-up Area':
            area_type =0
        elif area_type == 'Plot Area':
            area_type = 1
        elif area_type == 'Built-up Area':
            area_type = 2
        else:
            area_type = 3
        predict_list =np.zeros(134)
        predict_list[0]=area_type
        predict_list[1]=result["bedroom"]
        predict_list[2]=result["sqft"]
        predict_list[3]=result["bathroom"]
        predict_list[4]=result["year"]
        return "Estimated Price of your house is ₹"+str(round(model.predict([predict_list])[0],2))+" lakhs"
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: You seem to access data from flask without reloading page fir that you need to use [ajax and flask]. There are many tutorials for the same.

Comment: ok, I see, obviously You will get a blank page with just the text: `"Estimated Price of your..."` because that is the only thing that You are returning in that case, You should return the whole template, just pass that string as a variable to the template